# Getting positional index out of bound error

Tags: python, python-3.x, roc, auc

I'm loading data from a folder by using this code:

```
Diabetes=pd.read_csv('datasource/ScoringDatasheet.csv')
```

I'm using this code because there are 61 columns in my `csv`.

```
inputData=Diabetes.iloc[:,:62]
outputData=Diabetes.iloc[:,62]
```

Then I'm using `logistic regression` to plot `ROC`

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logit1=LogisticRegression()
logit1.fit(inputData,outputData)

logit1.score(inputData,outputData)



np.mean(logit1.predict(inputData)==outputData)

trueInput=Diabetes.ix[Diabetes['Outcome']==1].iloc[:,:62]
trueOutput=Diabetes.ix[Diabetes['Outcome']==1].iloc[:,62]

np.mean(logit1.predict(trueInput)==trueOutput)

falseInput=Diabetes.ix[Diabetes['Outcome']==0].iloc[:,:62]
falseOutput=Diabetes.ix[Diabetes['Outcome']==0].iloc[:,62]

np.mean(logit1.predict(falseInput)==falseOutput)





from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, roc_curve, roc_auc_score
confusion_matrix(logit1.predict(inputData),outputData)


fpr, tpr,_=roc_curve(logit1.predict(inputData),outputData,drop_intermediate=False)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='red', lw=2, label='ROC curve')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='blue', lw=2, linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('False Positive ')
plt.ylabel('True Positive ')
plt.title('ROC curve')
plt.show()


roc_auc_score(logit1.predict(inputData),outputData)

coef_DF=pd.DataFrame(data={'Variable':list(inputData),
'value':(logit1.coef_[0])})

coef_DF_standardised=pd.DataFrame(data={'Variable':list(inputData),
'value':(logit1.coef_[0])*np.std(inputData,axis=0)/np.std(outputData)})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(inputData.iloc[:,1],inputData.iloc[:,5],c=logit1.predict_proba(inputData)[:,1],alpha=0.4)
plt.xlabel('Glucose level ')
plt.ylabel('BMI ')
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(inputData.iloc[:,1],inputData.iloc[:,5],c=outputData,alpha=0.4)
plt.xlabel('Glucose level ')
plt.ylabel('BMI ')
plt.show()
```

Don't worry about labels. I can change them later, but I'm getting error as given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 9, in <module>
    outputData=Diabetes.iloc[:,62]
  File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2013, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 222, in _has_valid_tuple
    self._validate_key(k, i)
  File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1957, in _validate_key
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2009, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Is number of columns correct or am I missing anything here?

Comment: python counts from `0`, so need `Diabetes.iloc[:,:60]` and `outputData=Diabetes.iloc[:,60]` if `61` columns? (or 61 if counted index)

Comment: Well, I tried both `60` and `61`, getting same error for both values

Comment: What is `separator` in `datasource/ScoringDatasheet.csv` ? Is it comma?

Comment: It is `semicolon (;)`

Comment: So use `Diabetes=pd.read_csv('datasource/ScoringDatasheet.csv', sep=';')`

Comment: Modified as you told, getting new error now, `In line logit1.fit(inputData,outputData),  File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py", line 1221, in fit
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 171, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'`